# To call a function when user logins to a website with facebook

Tags: facebook

I am integrating facebook login to my website. I want to store information of users who logins with facebook. After login another page should be loaded. How to call a function when user logins to the website?

Answer (score 0):

While this will obviously depend on how you are actually logging in to facebook in the first place (using the PHP SDK, Javascript or whatever), if you are doing it correctly, you will be specifying a URL to go to upon successful login. All you need do is add a parameter to that url, and you will be able to detect that you logged in via facebook.

So your URL might be something like:

http://www.mysite.com/loginsuccess.php?source=fb

If you want further help can you outline how you are actually running the login process?

Comment: I am using facebook javascript SDK.function fbLogin() 
 {
FB.login(function (response) 
 } this is the login function. Where should I write a call to a function on login click.

Comment: I solved the problem..Call the function inside FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
  {....}